# Attempting to download a file from another project within solution when executing exe, Access is Denied error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm not sure entirely what could be the issue here.

I'm attempting to building a project that uses a .dll from another project within my solution. When I go to build the project, when it hits an Initialize, it errors out and says that it's "Attempting download of new url file://projectName/bin/debug/fileName.dll" A fatal error and that Access is Denied to that .dll

Set up: network machine where I'm compiling the project

Things I've done already:

1.) Removed read-only flag from all files
2.) Full access to all users to all files/folders
3.) logged in as Admin with full access
4.) running VS as Admin as well

not sure what else to try to get this to debug correctly.

Comment: Can you manually rebuild other project?

Comment: Yes, and they build and run correctly. just this one project, not sure if it's a setting or not that could be preventing it.

Comment: Something in project is calling a URL that doesn't get called when other project run by themselves.  You may want to use menu debug : break all to stop while app is trying to access the URL.  Then use menu debug : Windows : Call Stack to see how app got to point where URL is being opened.